# Load external URL in trigger.io UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, trigger.io

I have a pre-existing backbone application (made to be loaded in a native iOS `UIWebView`) that I'm trying to (quickly) migrate over to [trigger.io](https://trigger.io/) in order to make use of the easy image caching/access to the camera.

So far I've tried setting `window.location` in a tiny shim, but this causes trigger.io to forward the URL request to mobile safari. I also created a native module and tried loading a request on the webView directly, as well as calling `loadURL` on the `ForgeViewController`. Both had the same effect of launching mobile safari.

I'd love to be able to serve my application in its current form while also being able to take advantage of trigger.io's features. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible, but disabled by default to prevent external websites gaining access to native functionality.

To enable this add your site to the `trusted urls` setting under `general` in the app config. URLs should follow chrome style match patterns documented here: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html

Comment: This works fine but is there a way to remove the top title area and the empty bottom navigation area? I'd like to hide the two sections indicated here: http://note.io/1getBvS

Thanks